# Populating TableView with multiple sections and multiple dictionary in an array in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, dictionary

I have a 3 category which I was using as a section. In that section I have to populate data which is in array of dictionary. Here is my code:-

```
var sections = [Category A, Category B, Category C]
var itemsA = [["Item": "item A","ItemId" : "1"],["Item": "item B","ItemId" : "2"],["Item": "item C","ItemId" : "3"]]
var itemsB = [["Item": "item A","ItemId" : "1"],["Item": "item B","ItemId" : "2"],["Item": "item C","ItemId" : "3"]]
var itemsC = [["Item": "item A","ItemId" : "1"],["Item": "item B","ItemId" : "2"],["Item": "item C","ItemId" : "3"]]

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.sections.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return self.sections[section]
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return ??
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StoreCell") as! UITableViewCell
    ????
    ????
    return cell
}
```

The items array I need to populate into table category wise. If anyone can answer. Thank you!

Comment: I am unable to undestand your question.

Comment: Is itemA array for Category A?'

Comment: yes  it is an array of category A@NiravD

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If itemA array for Category A, itemB array for Category B and so on then you can return array count in `numberOfRowsInSection` this way.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch (section) {
        case 0: 
           return itemsA.count
        case 1: 
           return itemsB.count
        default: 
           return itemsC.count
     }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StoreCell") as! UITableViewCell
    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0: 
           //Access itemsA[indexPath.row]
        case 1: 
           //Access itemsB[indexPath.row]
        default: 
           //Access itemsC[indexPath.row]
     }
     return cell
}
```

**Note:** It is batter if you create single Array of struct or custom class that will reduce all your array with single array.

Comment: Okay and for cellForRowAtIndexPath what I have to do?

Comment: @shahinaliagharia Same goes for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, Check the edited answer.

Comment: In cellForRowAtIndexPath it gives an error for section, unresolved identifier.

Comment: @shahinaliagharia Forgot to add indexPath it indexPath.section check the edited answer.

Comment: @shahinaliagharia Can you please give reason of suddenly un accepting of answer so I can improve my answer.

Comment: suddenly its not showing any data because itemA comes in place of itemB and vice versa @NiravD

Comment: I was wrong your answer is absolutely right. Sorry for un accepting your answer

Comment: Sorry for misleading @NIrav D

Comment: I have a search controller to search for an item but i dont know how to implement with multiple sections, could you please help me out.

Comment: Ok I will do it now

Comment: Here it is question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43609615/search-controller-with-multiple-section-in-uitableview-swift-3

Answer (score 28):

Use a custom struct

```
struct Category {
   let name : String
   var items : [[String:Any]]
}
```

---

```
var sections = [Category]()

let itemsA = [["Item": "item A","ItemId" : "1"],["Item": "item B","ItemId" : "2"],["Item": "item C","ItemId" : "3"]]
let itemsB = [["Item": "item A","ItemId" : "1"],["Item": "item B","ItemId" : "2"],["Item": "item C","ItemId" : "3"]]
let itemsC = [["Item": "item A","ItemId" : "1"],["Item": "item B","ItemId" : "2"],["Item": "item C","ItemId" : "3"]]


sections = [Category(name:"A", items:itemsA), 
            Category(name:"B", items:itemsB), 
            Category(name:"C", items:itemsC)]
```

---

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.sections.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return self.sections[section].name
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let items = self.sections[section].items
    return items.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StoreCell") as! UITableViewCell
    let items = self.sections[indexPath.section].items
    let item = items[indexPath.row]
    print(item["ItemId"] as? String)

    return cell
}
```

You can still improve the code if you are using a custom struct also for the dictionaries.

Comment: I implemented the above answer but its not showing any data in table@vadian

Comment: Do you call `reloadData()` after setting up the data source ?

Comment: The code in my answer does not assign text to any label because I don't know the design of your cell. You need to add those line(s). But it should print the `ItemId` values into the console.

Comment: I added the lines but still not getting.. here is the line cell.storeName.text = item["Item"] as? String

Comment: It seems you are using a custom cell class. Then you need to cast the cell to this custom class in the `.dequeueReusableCell` line.

Comment: let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StoreCell") as! NearByTableViewCell....this is what I am doing for dequeue

Comment: And is the class of the cell set to `NearByTableViewCell` in Interface Builder? And is the print line working?

Comment: Actually it is working fine with the NiravD answer but suddenly i got to know that the itemA and itemB can change the position so I thought let me use your answer

Comment: I tested my code successfully in a sample project so the reason of the error must be somewhere else.