# Does indexpath.row take care of iterating an array?

Tags: ios, swift, nsindexpath

I'm working through a `UITableView` tutorial and I've become curious about array iteration as I implement the `UITableViewDataSource` methods.  When we call `indexPath.row`, is this calling a for loop for us behind the scenes?  I'm asking because months back when I was learning to use data from a webservice (I've forgotten the exact steps of how I did it precisely) but I believe I needed to iterate over the array in order to present the information in the console.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // Create an instance of UITableViewCell, with default appearance
        let cell = UITableViewCell.init(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: "UITableViewCell")

        // Set the text on the cell with the description of the item instance that is at the nth index of the allItems array, where n = row this cell will appear in on the tableview
        let item = itemStore.allItems[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = item.name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "$\(item.valueInDollars)"

        return cell
    }
```

Am I correct in thinking that the `indexPath.row` method is iterating over the array for us behind the scenes?

```
let item = itemStore.allItems[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: `indexPath.row` is just a number.  By itself, it doesn't do any work...including iteration.  However, there is iteration by the caller, resulting in requests for cells matching different row numbers.

Comment: FYI - your code for creating a cell is wrong. You should be dequeueing a reusable cell from the table view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, calling `indexPath.row` does not iterate through all rows for you. It's just a variable sent to `cellForRowAt` that you can access and use to create your cell. It contains information about which row in which section the function `cellForRowAt` was called for.

However, `cellForRowAt` is actually called every time a cell is going to be visible on your **tableVIew**. Imagine you have a **dataSource** with 100 items and it is possible to only see 10 cells at a time. When the **tableView** gets initially loaded, `cellForRowAt` will get called 10 times. Then, if you scroll your **tableView** to show 3 more cells, `cellForRowAt` will get called 3 more times.

Answer (score 1):

No.  The `indexPath` is just a struct with a `section` and a `row`.  You use those to directly look up the information from your array.  No iteration is happening.

`cellForRowAt` is only called for the cells that are on screen, so the order they are called depends on which direction you are scrolling.

In fact, the `UITableView` doesn't even know if you are using an array, or generating the information on the fly.  What you do with the `indexPath` `row` and `section` is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the tutorial seems to be pretty bad. Table view cells are supposed to be reused

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UITableViewCell", for: indexPath)
```

The workflow to display table view cells is:

- The framework calls `numberOfRowsInSection` (and also `numberOfSections`)
- For each section/row pair in the range of the visible cells it calls `cellForRowAt` and passes the index path in the second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation of UITableView and cellForRowAtIndexpath functions.

> An index path locating a row in tableView.

IndexPath will be a structure, which helps you to get the specific location from a nested array. In your case of the table view, rows inside the section.

cellForRow will return a cell for particular index path(in the specified section and row)

So indexPath.section will give the section number for which the cell is going to be modified and returned to the data source. And Inside the section, and indexPath.row will be the corresponding row inside that section.

[index path documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/indexpath)

[tableView-CellForRowAt: IndexPath](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614861-tableview)

[UITableView DataSource Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource)

[update]

If you want to add multiple sections, add another dataSource [numberOfSections](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614860-numberofsections), and return the number of sections count from it.

I can link to a [create a table view tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/CreateATableView.html) from Apple, but it's a long document, you can skip the starting and read the **To display a section in your table view**.

If you want, you can use a 2D array for keeping sections and rows. And in *numberOfSections* method return array.count, and in *numberOfRows:inSection*, return array[section].count

More examples,

- [example](https://gist.github.com/licvido/a78f3714a7eda01b3c62)
- [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42552611/populating-tableview-with-multiple-sections-and-multiple-dictionary-in-an-array)

thanks,
J

Comment: based on your answer can I ask, in order to have a tableView with two sections will I need to pass in an array within an array?