# Sections and cells in swift Xcode

Tags: swift, cell

I'm a newbie app developer and I'm having trouble displaying multiple sections and cells in my app. What's the best way to display 2 sections, 3 cells in the first section and 2 cells in the second section?

Comment: You'll need to show some code to show what you're trying to do. And explain what exa toy isn't working.

Comment: https://medium.com/swift-programming/swift-enums-and-uitableview-sections-1806b74b8138

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42552611/populating-tableview-with-multiple-sections-and-multiple-dictionary-in-an-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's reasonably easy.

1. Create a class that will be a subclass of TableViewController. The best way to do it is by clicking command+N, selecting CocoaTouch class, and then naming your class and choosing "UITableViewController" in the "subclass of" section. The resulting class will be called something like this:

```
    class NewsViewController: UITableViewController
```

2. In your class, define the required number of sections in the "numberOfSections" function like so:

```
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }
```

3. Define the required number of cells in numberOfRowsInSection method like so:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 {
            return 3
        } else {
            return 2
        }
    }
```

4. Populate your cells in the cellForRowAt indexPath method. The following code will return cells identifying their position in their respective sections. Don't forget to set the name of your cell to "informationCell" in Main.storyboard.

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "informationCell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = "This is a cell with ID: \(indexPath.row)"

        return cell
    }
```

Let me know if you have any additional questions. Good luck with your Swift learning!

Answer (score 0):

Just Handle in **numberOfRowsInSection** -

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0{
           return 3
        }else{
            return 2
        }
    }     


 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

       return 2

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to do something like this. Just make sure to replace `YourCellIdentifier` and `YourCellClass` with whatever you have.

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 {
            return 3
        } else if section == 1 {
            return 2
        }
        return 0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
            withIdentifier: "YourCellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! YourCellClass

        // configure your cell here

        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> > Here is the complete example of section table

```
let MovieData = [
      ["title": "Jason Bourne", "cast": "Matt Damon, Alicia Vikander, Julia Stiles", "genre": "action"],
      ["title": "Suicide Squad", "cast": "Margot Robbie, Jared Leto, Will Smith", "genre": "action"],
      ["title": "Star Trek Beyond", "cast": "Chris Pine, Zachary Quinto, Zoe Saldana", "genre": "action"],
      ["title": "Deadpool", "cast": "Ryan Reynolds, Morena Baccarin, Gina Carano", "genre": "action"],
      ["title": "London Has Fallen", "cast": "Gerard Butler, Aaron Eckhart, Morgan Freeman, Angela Bassett", "genre": "action"],
      ["title": "Ghostbusters", "cast": "Kate McKinnon, Leslie Jones, Melissa McCarthy, Kristen Wiig", "genre": "comedy"],
      ["title": "Central Intelligence", "cast": "Dwayne Johnson, Kevin Hart", "genre": "comedy"],
      ["title": "Bad Moms", "cast": "Mila Kunis, Kristen Bell, Kathryn Hahn, Christina Applegate", "genre": "comedy"],
      ["title": "Keanu", "cast": "Jordan Peele, Keegan-Michael Key", "genre": "comedy"],
      ["title": "Neighbors 2: Sorority Rising", "cast": "Seth Rogen, Rose Byrne", "genre": "comedy"],
      ["title": "The Shallows", "cast": "Blake Lively", "genre": "drama"],
      ["title": "The Finest Hours", "cast": "Chris Pine, Casey Affleck, Holliday Grainger", "genre": "drama"],
      ["title": "10 Cloverfield Lane", "cast": "Mary Elizabeth Winstead, John Goodman, John Gallagher Jr.", "genre": "drama"],
      ["title": "A Hologram for the King", "cast": "Tom Hanks, Sarita Choudhury", "genre": "drama"],
      ["title": "Miracles from Heaven", "cast": "Jennifer Garner, Kylie Rogers, Martin Henderson", "genre": "drama"],
    ]

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

      @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

      // The magic enum to end our pain and suffering!
      // For the most part the order of our cases do not matter.
      // What is important is that our first case is set to 0, and that our last case is always `total`.
      enum TableSection: Int {
        case action = 0, comedy, drama, indie, total
      }

      // This is the size of our header sections that we will use later on.
      let SectionHeaderHeight: CGFloat = 25

      // Data variable to track our sorted data.
      var data = [TableSection: [[String: String]]]()

      override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        sortData()
      }

      override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        tableView.reloadData()
      }

      // When generating sorted table data we can easily use our TableSection to make look up simple and easy to read.
      func sortData() {
        data[.action] = MovieData.filter({ $0["genre"] == "action" })
        data[.comedy] = MovieData.filter({ $0["genre"] == "comedy" })
        data[.drama] = MovieData.filter({ $0["genre"] == "drama" })
        data[.indie] = MovieData.filter({ $0["genre"] == "indie" })
      }

    }

    extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

      // As long as `total` is the last case in our TableSection enum,
      // this method will always be dynamically correct no mater how many table sections we add or remove.
      func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return TableSection.total.rawValue
      }

      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Using Swift's optional lookup we first check if there is a valid section of table.
        // Then we check that for the section there is data that goes with.
        if let tableSection = TableSection(rawValue: section), let movieData = data[tableSection] {
          return movieData.count
        }
        return 0
      }

      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        // If we wanted to always show a section header regardless of whether or not there were rows in it,
        // then uncomment this line below:
        //return SectionHeaderHeight

        // First check if there is a valid section of table.
        // Then we check that for the section there is more than 1 row.
        if let tableSection = TableSection(rawValue: section), let movieData = data[tableSection], movieData.count > 0 {
          return SectionHeaderHeight
        }
        return 0
      }

      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.width, height: SectionHeaderHeight))
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 253.0/255.0, green: 240.0/255.0, blue: 196.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 15, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.width - 30, height: SectionHeaderHeight))
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15)
        label.textColor = UIColor.black
        if let tableSection = TableSection(rawValue: section) {
          switch tableSection {
          case .action:
            label.text = "Action"
          case .comedy:
            label.text = "Comedy"
          case .drama:
            label.text = "Drama"
          case .indie:
            label.text = "Indie"
          default:
            label.text = ""
          }
        }
        view.addSubview(label)
        return view
      }

      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        // Similar to above, first check if there is a valid section of table.
        // Then we check that for the section there is a row.
        if let tableSection = TableSection(rawValue: indexPath.section), let movie = data[tableSection]?[indexPath.row] {
          if let titleLabel = cell.viewWithTag(10) as? UILabel {
            titleLabel.text = movie["title"]
          }
          if let subtitleLabel = cell.viewWithTag(20) as? UILabel {
            subtitleLabel.text = movie["cast"]
          }
        }
        return cell
      }

    }
```

> > result is

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This was also very helpful~